# git clone is failing in jenkins with fatal: index-pack failed

Tags: git, github, jenkins

Git clone fails with the below error in my jenkins pipeline

```
Receiving objects:  82% (158102/191432), 4.79 GiB | 4.80 MiB/s   
Killed by signal 15.
  fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
  fatal: early EOF
  fatal: index-pack failed
```

If I manually clone on my machine it works fine, but through pipeline this error occurs.
This error occurs 9 out of 10 times I run the pipeline.

Any idea how this can be resolved?

Jenkinsfile

```
stage('SCM') {
            steps {
                script {
                    FAILED_STAGE = env.STAGE_NAME
                }
                node('git') {
                ws( "${MY_DIR}" ) {
                    retry(0) {
                        checkout ([$class: 'GitSCM',
                                   poll: true,
                                   changelog: true,
                                   branches: [[name: params.GitBranch]],
                                   doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
                                   extensions: [[$class: 'GitLFSPull'],
                                                [$class: 'CleanBeforeCheckout'],
                                                [$class: 'PruneStaleBranch'],
                                                [$class: 'CheckoutOption', timeout: 120],
                                                [$class: 'SubmoduleOption',
                                                        disableSubmodules: false,
                                                        parentCredentials: false,
                                                        recursiveSubmodules: true,
                                                        reference: '',
                                                        trackingSubmodules: false]
                                               ],
                                   submoduleCfg: [],
                                   userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'APPGHEAccessTokenWithUsername',
                                                        url: 'https://github.com/AppDev/front-end.git']]
                        ])
                        sleep (1)
                    }
                       
                }
              }
            }
        }
```

Comment: "signal 15" is `SIGTERM`, which is often used for timeouts. Do you have something that times out your clone? (`timeout: 120` looks suspect!) If so, try giving it more time to complete, or using a faster cloning method (e.g., keep a local reference clone).

Comment: I have a similar issue, no "Killed by signal 15" but only the fatal errors and also works by one of 5 attempts. For now I ended up with setting `retry(5)` option for checkout stage, for I don't need to restart it manually. Timeout by my is 7 times bigger, than checkout needs, when it works. Try to build on another nodes, if there are any, which maybe have different configuration (if there is a bug by one of plugins)